# How to handle custom security on each page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms

This might sound like a stupid question, but I am about to implement a custom security database and framework for a new site.  I was wondering how best to handle this.

NOTE:  I am NOT using the ASP.NET Membership for this, I am using a custom database and everything custom for user management.

There will be several levels of security, so I am a bit stumped on this without making it too difficult.  The only thing I could think of so far is check on EVERY PAGE in the Page_Load if they have the right security:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CustomUser user = Session["User"] as CustomUser;
     if(user != null && user.CanAccessFeature("TopicModeration"))
     {
          //initialize page elements
     }
     else 
     {
          Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?featureDenied=TopicModeration", false);
          Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
     }
}
```

That works fine, but if I have dozens of pages that have different restrictions, it can get a bit repetitive.  Does anybody have any thoughts on this?  Should I inherit from System.Web.Page for each security feature, and use that on the page instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Masterpage? If so, do authentication in the Masterpage load event

Comment: @TheShaman I am using a standard master page for all pages, but like I said there are many security features.  Should I make a master page for each security feature and check it there?

Comment: IMHO a lot depends on those "roles" or "groups"/"levels" (what you call "features") - even if you're not using Membership, the concepts hopefully apply to your implementation. Kinda like [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) :)

Comment: @EdSF Well if a user cannot use the feature that the page needs, that user will need to be redirected to a standard page.  In that case, should I create a BasePage class for each feature?  Like ModerationPage, AdministrationPage, ...?

Comment: If you can group them in a logical manner that fits your implementation, then yes (for a "grouping"). If they are truly "unique" then it's sort of irrelevant - I doubt this would be the case (e.g. "Admin Page" access is granted to "admin role" that will likely inherit most, if not all, the "lesser" roles - inherits "user", "moderator", etc...)

Comment: @EdSF Yes that is what I am planning.  So each base page will check its respective role.  So if I have 8 custom roles, I would need 8 base pages?

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest the following approach:

Create a custom controller class as such:

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        CustomUser user = Session["User"] as CustomUser;
        if(user != null && user.CanAccessFeature("TopicModeration"))
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Default.aspx?featureDenied=TopicModeration", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you may have your controllers where you want that check to inherit from this controller.

Comment: I am using webforms, will this work or is it only for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I am really sorry but i wouldn't know how to do this in web forms. I know you can mix MVC with WEB Forms, but i do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Base Class and make all master pages (or pages) inherit that class.

Here is an example when a Master Page inherits a class.

1. Class for all master pages to inherit.

   ```
   public class PageBase: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
   {       
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
      {
          //Put your security code here...
          base.OnLoad(e);
      }  
   }
   ```
2. Here is a Master page inheriting the class above.

   ```
   public partial class Site1ColMaster : MySite.PageBase
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         //Master page
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: So would I need to make a base class for each security feature?  Like a base class for: TopicModeration, TopicAdministration, PostAdministration, PostModeration, Chat, Downloads, ...?